# OpenESB on Glassfish v3?

Tags: glassfish, open-esb

Does anyone know if OpenESB components, any version, can run on Glassfish v3?  Or is OpenESB now a deadend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a white paper which provides a real world insight on the future of OpenESB. It's past, Present and Future. OpenESB V3 is work in progress and the release of the same would be announced in NEXT OpenESB Summit in USA.
http://www.logicoy.com/userfiles/openesb-past_present_future_news_letter.pdf